# Indicator to variable in array instead of variable in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have following part of my code:

```
private engineSpeed = 0;
private gearboxTemp = 0; 
private engine = {
  "Temp1" : ["30 °C", "30 °C", "30 °C"],
  "Param" : ["17.23 kPa", "1200 m³/min", "0.7 kg/m³", "55 °C"],
  "Speed" : [this.engineSpeed + " rpm"]
}


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataWatchdog = setInterval(async () => {  
    this.engineSpeed = await this.getEngineSpeed()
  }, 5000)
}


public button()
{
    console.log("Speed ", this.engine["Speed"])
    console.log("Engine speed", this.engineSpeed )
}
```

I am updating `this.engineSpeed` variable in each 5s in dataWatchdog. But still in engine array `this.engineSpeed` value is not updated and in `console.log` I am getting the `0`.

[Result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDqLJ.png)

Is it possible to have an indicatior to `this.engineSpeed` variable in array instead of just a variable and keep it updated? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Your async/await does not seem relevant. What is the content of `getEngineSpeed()` ? 2) if you update `this.engineSpeed`, you have to manually update `this.engine.Speed[0]`, you may do it in the `set engineSpeed(newValue)` method to keep it up to date

Comment: 1) getEngineSpeed() is just reading value from data base it is not relevant here I just wanted to show that value is constanly updated. 
2) This is sad because I wanted to add many variables like this and possibly modify their position so this.engine.Speed[0] not always will be working because sometimes it can be like
{"Speed" : [this.engineSpeed + " rpm"]} or "Speed" : [this.engineSpeed1 + "rpm",this.engineSpeed2 + " rpm" ] and then I don't dant to put this.engine.Speed[0] and this.engine.Speed[1]

Comment: so @kruschid solution seems to be the best way to do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a new value to `this.engineSpeed` doesn't implicitly update the value of `this.engine.Speed[0]` because the `this.engineSpeed + " rpm"` is only interpreted once and contains a copy of the initial value of `this.engineSpeed`. You could update `this.engine.Speed[0]` imperatively in your "watchdog", create a `getSpeed` method or do something like this:

```
private engine = {
  // ...
  "Speed" : () => [this.engineSpeed + " rpm"] // Speed is now a function
}

public button()
{
    console.log("Speed ", this.engine["Speed"]())
    console.log("Engine speed", this.engineSpeed )
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, this is working as I expected :)